# Special letters in Vietnamese become "???" on VHLSS Data

Tags: stata, stata-macros, readstata13

[image]
I have a dataset named 'vhlss' that uses a certain font. Somehow, when I import it into Stata, the text appears like this. Even though I've adjusted the font settings in Stata, and it's Stata 18.

I wish to know how to revert the text to normal without having to set it line by line because the dataset has too many questions to manually adjust each one

Comment: What is the file format of your data before you import it to Stata?

Comment: We can’t tell you the correct encoding without seeing (a representative, ideally small sample of) the actual contents of the data in an unambiguous representation; a hex dump of the problematic byte(s) with a few bytes of context on each side is often enough, especially if you can tell us what you think those bytes are supposed to represent. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: I can't reproduce your problem.**

I tried replicating your issue by creating the following .csv file:

```
name
Tuđi
Giêi Tănh
Nhung Trương Thị Kiều
```

and importing it into Stata:

```
import delimited "/Users/moritz/Downloads/test.csv", varnames(1) clear
```

This import method uses UTF-8 font encoding by default and all characters show up just fine in Stata. I even tried every other available font encoding and none looked like your screenshot (which doesn't look like Stata to begin with).

[image: Stata screenshot]

I also went into Stata's Data Editor settings and played with the data display fonts but none of those gave any issues. Please let us know what file format you are using (or better post your data) so we can help you better.

Finally, since you used the `readstata13` tag (which is an R command), I saved this test data set to `.dta` and imported it into R with `read.dta13()` (the command of the tagged package) and again, the import went completely smoothly:

[image: R screenshot]

FWIW, [this link](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1465626-unicode-encoding-_-vietnamese-letters) might help with some Vietnamese alphabet specific problems.